# Rust linking error while compiling with mongodb driver

Tags: mongodb, linker, rust

I've been bumping my head against this, I've tried all dependency versions but the compiler could not find a method to link with:

My Cargo.toml looks like this:

```
[package]
name    = "mongotest"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["netwave"]

[dependencies]
bson       = "*"
mongodb    = "0.1.7"
```

It all compiles properly, but when linking it could not find `gethostname`

> C:\Users\netwave.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\bson-0.3.1\src/oid.rs:205:
>   undefined reference to `gethostname'

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I installed the GNU version of GCC on my computer, mingw-64 with GCC 6.1. This does not work properly.

Installing the MSVC version of the Rust compiler makes it work perfectly.